# ¿Es el español de Perú y/o Ecuador realmente más cercano al europeo?

Tags: diferencias-regionales, perú, ecuador

Recientemente estuve con una persona que estudia español, siendo este idioma una lengua extranjera para ella. Me dijo con toda seguridad:

> El español de Perú y Ecuador, por ejemplo, se conservaron más fieles al español de España, que el español de otros países latinoamericanos.

¿Alguien conce algún estudio serio que soporte esta afirmación?

Comment: me imagino que lo dirá por el voseo, aunque en realidad no sé en Perú si lo usan, si se que en Ecuador se usa el voseo

Comment: Esto no responde a tu pregunta que tiene el problema de definir qué entendemos por _'cercano'_, pero seguramente te será útil leer, a modo de antecedente, este ensayo de Jesús Sánchez Lobato sobre el Español en América: http://cvc.cervantes.es/ensenanza/biblioteca_ele/asele/pdf/04/04_0553.pdf

Comment: El "español" o "castellano" de ambos países es semejante. El de México también.
Pero el de Argentina... "Che viejo, dormí pronto"

Comment: El de Ecuador desde luego que no.  El de Perú se aproxima más.

Answer (score 8):

El problema con una pregunta como esa es que primero hay que definir lo que se quiere decir con «más cercano».

¿Trátase de pronunciación?  ¿de gramática?  ¿de vocabulario?

¿Trátase del registro vulgar? ¿culto? ¿campestre? ¿esmero?

Y una vez establecida tal definición, hay que especificar lo que se entiende al hablar de «España».  ¿La España actual?  ¿La España de la que surgieron las múltiples variedades de castellano/español en el Nuevo Mundo, el África y el Asia?  Y si es la España actual pues sigue habiendo muchas distinciones entre zonas, algunas que han tenido más influencia que otras en uno u otro dialecto americano.

Comment: De todas maneras se podría completar con ejemplos de lo que se parece y lo que no, y si hay algún acento que se parezca más que ellos.// Cómo un comentario general, duele decirse que la pronunciación, en Colombia y Perú, suele ser más esmerada que entre sus vecinos, a todo nivel

Comment: Ufff, no me fijé en el autocorrector: "Como un comentario general, suele decirse que..."

Answer (score 4):

No sé cuál se acerca más al español de España, aunque hay que considerar que dentro de la misma España hay diferencias regionales. Por ejemplo, el español de Chile (mi país), precisamente el acento de la zona central, se parece mucho al de Andalucía, debido a que muchos conquistadores que llegaron a Chile eran andaluces.

Comment: Encuentro que la pronunciación que se hace en Chile es muy parecida a la de España (¿quizá es el país de América que más?) Aunque supongo que variará mucho entre regiones

Comment: @Pere, sí, varía entre regiones. Por eso digo el acento de la zona central, ya que es el más, digamos, neutro. Porque el del extremo norte, por ejemplo, es bastante similar al peruano. Y el del extremo sur es muy especial, no se parece a ninguno. El español de la zona central de Chile se parece al andaluz. Puedes buscar vídeos en YouTube de los noticiarios chilenos (24 horas, Teletrece, Aquí noticias) para hacer comparaciones ^_^

Comment: También están los acentos de niveles socieconómicos bajos, que son de gente con poca educación. A mí me cuesta entender aquellos acentos, por mucho que sea chilena. Es un fenómeno que se da en todos los países. Aquí se le llama acento flaite.

Comment: También el acento Venezolano es muy similar al Canario (Islas Canarias).

Comment: Siendo chileno, opino que el cubano es _mucho_ más parecido al andaluz que el chileno

Answer (score 2):

> "El español de Perú y Ecuador, por ejemplo, se conservaron más fieles al español de España, que el español de otros países latinoamericanos"

La frase es muy discutible. Además el español de España evolucionó en 500 años, por lo que si es verdad que el español de Perú es similar al de España (por ejemplo, dicen "hoy he comido" en lugar de "hoy comí") no se debe a que se haya conservado más fiel al original sino a que evolucionó más apegado a la metrópoli.

Answer (score 1):

Compartí esta pregunta en [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/ecuador/comments/5bt9x6/es_el_espa%C3%B1ol_de_per%C3%BA_yo_ecuador_realmente_m%C3%A1s/) y recibí una respuesta la mar de interesante:

> Alguna vez un amigo políglota de Texas, que era parte del staff del concurso Miss Universo, y que no es de origen latino, al oír hablar el español de Quito, Ecuador, me dijo, literal: " you (quiteños) don't speak Spanish, you speak Castilian". Su idea del "español" era distinta, luego de visitar algunos países del mundo por su trabajo y sobretodo escuchando habitualmente a latinoamericanos en Texas hablar "tex-mex". Es cierto que en ciertas partes rurales de Ecuador los acentos pueden ser acentuados, pero podría decirse que no existen grandes variaciones en cuanto al vocabulario cotidiano. La única gran diferencia con el español de España es la falta de pronunciación de las "z" y las "c" como consonantes denti-linguales. Obviamente nombres de algunas frutas, hortalizas y varios términos arcaicos provenientes del quichua estarán presentes, pero estos últimos serán más escasos en conversaciones de gente con educación superior.
>
> Dentro de los acentos del Ecuador, algunos consideran que en la provincia de Loja, al sur, se habla el español con menor acento.
>
> También a los Quiteños que han dejado ciertos malos hábitos de pronunciación como el arrastre excesivo de la "rr" o la "ll" se los considera con un acento neutro y claro. A veces son confundidos en otros países como mexicanos de Monterrey o del Distrito Federal.

Answer (score -1):

Las comparaciones de cualquiera de los acentos del castellano latinoamericano podría hacerse con seriedad en oposición al acento de los limeños, considerando estas particularidades: que 1 Residan en Lima urbana (los del entorno sub-urbano o barrios de los alrededores tienen influencia familiar regional por ser inmigrantes y usar jergas), 2 Posean léxico cultivado por lecturas y formas educadas, 3 Hayan permanecido en contacto auditivo con entornos educativos relativamente cultos desde su nacimiento (familias, maestros con correcta expresión), 4 Tengan antepasados con ambos apellidos hispanos o no nativos (los hablantes con apellidos quechuas, aymaras y otros, han adquirido un español con acentos regionales claramente diferenciados), 5 Sean jóvenes y adultos con intelecto promedio o superior (pues los menores en general no demuestran mayores capacidades asociativas en riqueza y calidad expresiva del español) y 6 Pronuncien sin poses y con autenticidad, además de madurez para respetar las variantes de otros hablantes del español. Sin considerar estos criterios no cabrían comparaciones. En suma, las comparaciones tendrían sentido solamente entre los acentos castellanos comprobadamente naturales (maternos) más cercanos al “neutro” artificial de limeños cultos, castellanos cultos y bogotanos cultos, y para quienes gusten alimentar falsos egos, también pueden forzar comparaciones entre hablantes hispanoamericanos cultos con cualesquiera de estos tres castellanos naturales. 
Ningún hablante de doblajes cuenta para comparar porque la voz doblada es el habla artificial entrenada para la actuación, siendo su forma natural o coloquial de expresarse la propia del lugar de origen de quien dobla. 
La voz doblada es pues, una imitación que intenta suprimir la voz natural recargada de acentos regionales. Los doblajes mexicanos son una industria con larga data entre los films norteamericanos. 
Vargas Llosa no es de Lima, nació en Arequipa, fue llevado a Cochabamba (Bolivia) en su infancia y en su pubertad vivió en Lima residencial. Jaime Bayly llega casi al 90% de estos requisitos, pero se expresa con poses y entona mucho el acento del limeño acomodado. César Hildebrandt, cuando fluye sin sarcasmo, llega casi al 100% del castellano natural más neutro. El acento de García Márquez es magdaleno https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YYojsHCkvCE.
Los locutores de emisoras radiales cultas de Lima (Perú), Castilla (España) y Bogotá (Colombia), serían, en concordancia con la opinión de linguístas reputados, los modelos del castellano natural más neutro y menos acentuado. Y probablemente, sea mejor aprender de ellos que de escuelas de doblaje o de instructores forzadamente neutros (actores mexicanos y otros). 
La explicación de que sean 1 los limeños y 2 los bogotanos cultivados, los mejores acentos en Latinoamérica, radica en el hecho que los nobles llegados de Castilla (más numerosos a Lima que a Bogotá y Ciudad de México –revísese-), impusieron su sonoridad vocal castellana en Lima y Bogotá sobre los hablantes nativos y afrodescendientes. Los nobles del virreinato del Perú, en Lima, se vinculaban mínimamente con la servidumbre quechuahablante, por ello es que se preserva hasta hoy la semejanza entre el acento de la Castilla culta y la Lima culta (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B1q_NIbAFts), exceptuándose los fonemas z, c y s, que se fueron perdiendo por el uso.